# XNA high CPU usage with different TargetElapsedTime

Tags: c#, windows, xna, cpu, frame-rate

With the same code i have:

5-10% CPU usage with `IsFixedTimeStep = true` and `TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1 / 60f)`

50-60% CPU usage with `IsFixedTimeStep = true` and `TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1 / 30f)`

by decreasing the frame rate one should expect less CPU usage.
I have tried with different code with similiar results.
Anyone know the cause?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess (which I have to, because you've provided very little information to go on), I'd say it's an interaction between the GPU and CPU.

Take a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2008/03/31/an-elf-in-a-box.aspx).

Basically, at 60 FPS, you're probably being GPU-limited. The CPU is sitting idle waiting for the GPU to draw a frame before it starts on drawing another one. You're probably dropping frames.

At 30 FPS, the GPU is able to keep up, and so the CPU has to send out frames more frequently.

But, again, this is just a guess. You'd have to instrument your code to properly check for these things.